# AudioKit how to update plot to change color or prototype

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I have used the AudioKit example code for microphone analysis, but I can't figure out how to make changes to the plot/graph.

```
 func setupPlot() {

    let plot = AKNodeOutputPlot(mic, frame: audioInputPlot.bounds)
    plot.plotType = .buffer
    plot.shouldFill = false
    plot.shouldMirror = false
    plot.color = color
    audioInputPlot.addSubview(plot)

}
```

I want to change the plot.color when I press a button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only issue here is that you're declaring plot as a local variable and can't access it from outside the setupPlot function. declare it as instance variable to the class and you should be able to change its color at any point.